# Automatically video play in chat bot emulator

Tags: c#, .net

I am Adding a videos card to my chat bot.

```
var resultMessage = context.MakeMessage();
            var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Videos/Cute.mp4"));
            string videoData = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            resultMessage.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
            resultMessage.Attachments = new List<Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Attachment>();
            VideoCard vc = new VideoCard()
            {
                // Title = $"hi",
                // Subtitle = Address,
                Media = new List<MediaUrl>()
                    {
                        new MediaUrl()
                        {
                          // Url = "https://i1.wp.com/thefreshimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/lord-shiva-hd-images.jpg?resize=3840%2C2160&ssl=1"
                          Url = "data:video/mp4;base64,"+ videoData

                        },
                    }
            };
            resultMessage.Attachments.Add(vc.ToAttachment());

            await context.PostAsync(resultMessage);
```

It will play When user click the play button .But I want to play automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Says [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d6/da6/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_connector_1_1_video_card.html#a2f2a1be9e9d129e3d6d651cbe4db2829) that Autostart property is true by default, so it should start playing automatically. You could try setting it to true and see if it works.

```
VideoCard vc = new VideoCard()
{
    Media = new List<MediaUrl>()
    {
        new MediaUrl()
        {
            // Url = "https://i1.wp.com/thefreshimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/lord-shiva-hd-images.jpg?resize=3840%2C2160&ssl=1"
            Url = "data:video/mp4;base64,"+ videoData
        }
    },
    Autostart = true
};
```